# Webpack - How to attach a script only to a given html file

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm not used to work with multiple html files with Webpack, and I'm wondering how I'm supposed to attach a given script to a given html page, since I don't want to load the whole bundle.js in every pages of my app.

I'm using HtmlWebpackPlugin and my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: './index.html',
        template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: './page2.html',
        template: './src/page2.html'
    })
]
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#filtering-chunks

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how chunks work though. What does "chunks: ['app']" mean ? That you load an app.js file ?

Comment: those can be the entry points for [example](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx) so you can point different html build to inject different entry points

Comment: So I understand that if you define the entry points this way: "entry: { main: './src/index.js', foobar: './src/js/mytestfile.js' }"
you should be able to attach foobar to a given HtmlWebpackPlugin instance this way "chunks: ['foobar']".
But it doesn't seem to be working so I must be missing something ;)

Comment: please create a minimal repo with your efforts and give me the link

Comment: Et voilà: https://bitbucket.org/thibka/20190216_htmlwebpackplugin_test/src
There are two js files, I'm just trying to load index.js in index.html, and js/page2.js in page2.html

Comment: With regards to error: please change in your webpack config `output.filename` to just `[name].bundle.js`, since you hardcode it to "./bundle.js" webpack cannot split them correctly, so you have different builds for different files. Other than that it works with multi entries.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot for your time Karen :)